# Zend Framework duplicates urls for SEO(webmaster tools) Same Url with /public and without /public

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite, google-search-console

I have a problem with duplicate urls. Webmaster tools says me I have duplicate titles and description. 
My web works with zend framework, and all the urls show the same information, with /public/ and without /public/ in the url.
here the sample

```
www.mydomain.com/public/sample

www.mydomain.com/sample
```

These urls show the same content.

There are some trick to put in .htacces to delete or redirect all urls with /public/ to without /public?

Here my .htacces, this file is inside /public/:

```
*SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^public/(.*) /$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]*
```

This will give a 301 redirect so Webmaster tools knows any content on public/* has been permanently moved, and this is where the content now belongs.